# Tools for optimizing asymptotic bounds.

Tags: computational-mathematics, math-software, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any tool for this task ?

Given the asymptotic bound in term of $n$ and other paramaters $t_1,\dots,t_r$, then return the value for each $t_i$ which optimizes the expression in term of $n$, asymptotically (may be upto constant factor $O(1)$, or even polynomial factor $n^{O(1)}$.

For example,

- $O(n/t+t)$, then $t=\sqrt{n}$ gives us  O($\sqrt{n}$).
- $O(n/t+2^t)$, then $t=\log{n}-\log\log{n}$ gives us  O($n/\log{n}$).

These are quite simple.

But when I see something like this from the paper..

- $\Omega( (\binom{n+k}{2k} \binom{n^2+l-2k}{l})/ (\binom{\sqrt{n}+k}{k}\binom{n^2+l+\sqrt{n}k}{n^2})$. Then $l=n^2t$ and $k=\Theta(n/t)$ gives us  $\exp(\Omega(\sqrt{n}))$.

I hope there are the computer tools which can optimize this.

Comment: For the first two, indeed it's quite simple: a good rule of thumb is "you have two terms, balance them" (so $n/t=t$, giving $t=\sqrt{n}$; same for the second). In general, you just want to maximize a function of several arguments under some constraints, which tools like Mathematica can do reasonably well.

Comment: For instance, for the last one, you could first get rid of all the Binomial coefficients using Stirling's approximation; then you have a simpler function of your 3 parameters which can easily be extended to continuous parameters, not just discrete, and for those, you can just use calculus.